# Session management with load balancer in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, load-balancing

We are developing a Java EE application with Spring. The application will be deployed across multiple web servers with hardware load balancer. Here are my doubts. Please clarify.

1. Whether load balancer will route all requests in same session to a single web server?
2. If not is there anyway to route the requests of same session to particular web server?

EDIT: Removed spring.

Comment: How is this a Spring question?

Comment: Google "Sticky sessions". Your load balancer should support them.

Comment: @NickWilson pls enter this as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're referring to here are "sticky sessions" and your load balancer should support them. It alllows the load balancer to use the session ID to route all requests for a session to the same server.